# Apache Spark:Why reduceByKey transformation executes the DAG?

Tags: apache-spark

I am facing a strange issue. As far as I understand, DAG of operations in Spark only executes when an action is performed. However, I can see that reduceByKey() opertation(being a transformation) starts executing the DAG.

Steps to reproduce . Try follwing piece of code

```
SparkConf conf =new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Test");
JavaSparkContext context=new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<String> textFile = context.textFile("any non-existing path"); // This path should not exist

JavaRDD<String> flatMap = textFile.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).iterator());
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> mapToPair = flatMap.mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>((String) x, 1));
```

Note: the path of the file should not be any existing path. In other words, file should not exist.

If you execute this code, nothing happens as expected.However if you add following line to the program and execute

```
mapToPair.reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y);
```

It gives following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:
```

It means it has started executing the DAG. Since reduceByKey() is a transformation, this should not be the case until an action such as collect() or take() is executed.

Spark version: 2.0.0. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: what do u mean by this line?JavaRDD<String> textFile = context.textFile("any non-existing path"); // This path should not exist

Comment: context.textFile() ideally loads the hdfs or local contents to an RDD. If the path doesnt exist , how will RDD get formed

Comment: @AviralKumar the question is concerned with why the code is being executed given that transformations are evaluated lazily. That the file doesn't exist and an exception is thrown after calling reduceByKey proves that *something* is being executed after a transformation.

Comment: @ImDarrenG : Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @AviralKumar: Reason I have asked specifically to provide non-existing path to explain that DAG is running even with transformations as it is throwing exception

Comment: @ImDarrenG I understand sth wrong, sorry. No, shuffling itself doesn't executes DAG. It just adds additional stage. Sorry for mistake and thanks for showing it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because, it's not really the DAG that gets executed (as in : the whole materialization of it).

What happens is that reduceByKey *needs* a Partitioner to work. If you do not provide one, Spark creates one based on conventions and defaults. The "default partiionner" as the following comments in the code :

```
/**
* Choose a partitioner to use for a cogroup-like operation between a number of RDDs.
*
* If any of the RDDs already has a partitioner, choose that one.
*
* Otherwise, we use a default HashPartitioner. For the number of partitions, if
* spark.default.parallelism is set, then we'll use the value from SparkContext
* defaultParallelism, otherwise we'll use the max number of upstream partitions.
*
* Unless spark.default.parallelism is set, the number of partitions will be the
* same as the number of partitions in the largest upstream RDD, as this should
* be least likely to cause out-of-memory errors.
*
* We use two method parameters (rdd, others) to enforce callers passing at least 1 RDD.
*/
```

This definition implies, that in some cases, the number of partitions from all upstream RDDs is calculated. In your case, that means asking the "file system" (could be Hadoop, could be local, ...) to perform whatever is necessary (e.g. a single call to a Hadoop FileSystem could return multiple files, each files can also be split according to various optimizations defined by its InputFormat, that can only be known by actually looking them up).

So that's what is getting executed here, not the actual DAG (e.g; your map/flatMap/aggregate, ...).

You could probably avoid it by providing your own partitionner in this reduce by key variant :

```
 reduceByKey(partitioner: Partitioner, func: (V, V) => V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tries providing custom Partitoner and it is nor throwing error now. However, I am still confused why it started calculating partitons if no action is executed.

Following is the partitioner code for reference:
`Partitioner partitioner = new Partitioner() {
   final int maxPartitions=2;
   @Override
   public int numPartitions() {
    
    return maxPartitions;
   }
   
   @Override
   public int getPartition(final Object obj) {
     String obj1 =(String) obj;
    return obj1.hashCode() % maxPartitions;
   }
  };
`

Comment: Because partitioners are not created "on the fly" on "action execution", but at the time transformations that need them are created. (It's more like a tradeoff than a shortcoming on Spark's part). The default one tries to be smart about it (e.g. if it created a small number of partitions, it could lead to Out of memories, if it created too many, it could be a waste), but being smart implies fetching upstream RDDs descriptions, which you call "calculating partitions". Setting the default parallelism parameter will switch that "off", if that's what you really want.

Comment: Your handmade Partitionner looks like a HashPartitionner, that Spark already has : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/HashPartitioner.html

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt.  I just wanted to try with same hash partitioner logic.